# X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true - specify - web request

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest, http-headers

I need to enclose this X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true in web request. Can you tell me related property to this. 
thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Headers.Add("X-MicrosoftAjax", "Delta=true");
...
```